# Get `lib` path of a globally installed node CLI tool

Tags: node.js

I have a node cli tool I'm developing called `wiki-sync`.

I need access to the path to the node_modules lib dir from within my node cli app at runtime. This path, in my case, looks like: `/Users/mchpatr/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/@parm/wiki-sync/`

I've tried many things and none of these seem to give me what I am looking for. I'm certain there's an easy way to do this and I'm just missing it.

Here's what I've tried from within `bin/wiki-sync`:

```
process.cwd()                         /Volumes/Unix/workplace/Parm/src/Parm
process.execPath                      /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0/bin/node
process.argv[1]                       /Users/mchpatr/.node_modules/bin/wiki-sync
fs.realpathSync(process.argv[1])      /Volumes/Unix/workplace/Parm/src/Parm/dist/apps/wiki-sync/bin/wiki-sync
which wiki-sync                       /Users/mchpatr/.node_modules/bin/wiki-sync
```

Answer (score 0):

[`require.resolve('@parm/wiki-sync')`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) will return the path to @parm/wiki-sync.

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) or [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename) will return the path to the files directory or the directory itself.